# PostgreSQL import large text file and ignore errors

Tags: postgresql

Basically I'm running Windows 10 and trying to import very large databases in a .txt format that are delimited. I'm aware of the COPY command, however some of the data is malformed and it's not a solution to fix the malformed rows. Therefore I'm seeking a way to import the large database and make it ignore errors. I've read about pgloader, but it seems way too tricky to make it work on windows.

Not that 'IGNORE' is not a solution!

Comment: Which programming languages / tools are at your disposal?

Comment: @Nicarus I know Java and I got the standard pgsql tools. I know it's possible to write a reader and create insert statements in Java, but assume it's like 50 GB+, I don't know how to write fast enough reader in Java for that.